# add a class when login

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

i add this code in `index.php`.
`<div class="Div1"></div>`. then write some css(absolution position) to the `Div1`. so when i login in my wordpress. the admin nav will push down some spaces to the site body. so the conetent shows unnormal. now, i want to add a `class` to `<div class="Div1">` when logins. is there a way to get this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function, a class `admin-bar` will be added automatically when the admin bar is active. For example:

```
<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar">
```

You can then use that class in your CSS to specify specific rules:

```
.admin-bar .Div1 { /* custom styles */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for this with a

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
```

And then use jquery to add class to div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".Div1").addClass("logged-in");
```

So you would use this

```
<?php 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".Div1").addClass("logged-in");
            '
    else
        echo '';
?>
```

Paste this in your functions.php file in the header.php or a plugin. Your choice. If the add class does not work try finding the div id that div1 class is inside of and use this instead 'jQuery("#divclassparent .Div1").addClass("logged-in");'